# ElasticSearch - Upgraded indexed field to a Multi Field - new field is empty

Tags: elasticsearch

Having noticed my sort on an indexed string field doesn't work properly, I've discovered that it's sorting analyzed strings so "bags of words" and if I want it to work properly I have to sort on the non-analyzed string. My plan was to just change the string field to a multi-field, using information I found in those two articles:

https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime  (Upgrade to a multi-field part)
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html

Using Sense I've created this field mapping

```
PUT myindex/_mapping/type
{
   "properties": {
      "Title": {
         "type": "string",
         "fields": {
            "Raw": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And then I try to sort my search results using the newly made field. I've put all of the name variations I could think of after reading the articles:

```
POST myindex/_search
{
    "_source" : ["Title","titlemap.Raw","titlemap.Title","titlemap.Title.Raw","Title.Title","Raw","Title.Raw"],
    "size": 6,
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "title",
            "fields": ["Title^5"
            ],
            "fuzziness": "auto",
            "type": "best_fields"
        }
    },
    "sort": {
        "Title.Raw": "asc"
    }
}
```

And that's what I get in response:

```
{
    "_index": "myindex_2015_11_26_12_22_38",
    "_type": "type",
    "_id": "1205",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
       "Title": "The title of the item"
    },
    "sort": [
       null
    ]
 }
```

Only the Title field's value is shown in the response and the sort criterium is null for every result.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there another way to do that?

Comment: Yes, you simply need to reindex your data, since the new `Raw` subfield is not populated yet.

Comment: @Val, I've tried that, but now my mapping is gone. The problem probably lies in the fact that myindex_2015_11_26_12_22_38 was the name of the index, while myindex is the alias.

Comment: You seem to have updated the `titlemap` type (see the URL `myindex/_mapping/titlemap`), but judging by the results you get the real type of your documents is `type` (see the `_type` field), so probably you haven't updated the right mapping. Your index/alias is `myindex`, your mapping type is `type`, your field you want to upgrade to a multi-field is `Title`. I don't know what `titlemap` is.

Comment: My bad, I've changed the url to myindex/_mapping/type, however, this still doesn't help. When reindexing, I create a new index (myindex_current_date) and then assign the myindex alias to it, unassigning the alias from the last index.
    `"reason": "No mapping found for [Title.Raw] in order to sort on"`

Comment: After creating the new index and the mapping, you can reindex. No reason the mapping would be gone after reindexing.

Comment: As I said, I've implemented reindexing based on this [article](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-aliases.html). So each time when I reindex data from my application, I actually create a new index and assign it to a generic alias (`myindex`).

Comment: And what mapping do you apply to your index before reindexing? Can you show what you get with `curl -XGET localhost:9200/myindex/_mapping`?

Comment: `{
   "myindex_2015_12_11_17_19_40": {
      "mappings": {
         "type": {
            "properties": {               
               "Title": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "fields": {
                     "Raw": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}`

As I've though the mapping is actually on the index and not on the alias. Is there a way to put it on the alias instead?

Comment: Mappings are always on the index, the alias is just a logical index, but doesn't contain mappings. So you have only a single `Title` field in your mapping? If you reindex data now, you should have your `Title.Raw` field populated properly. What happens next?

Comment: `{
   "myindex_2015_12_11_17_35_42": {
      "mappings": {
         "type": {
            "properties": {               
               "Title": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}`

New index is created and the mapping is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index name is not the same after re-indexing and thus the default mapping gets installed... that's probably why.

I suggest using an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) instead, so you don't have to care when to create the index and ES will do it for you. The idea is to create a template with the proper mapping you need and then ES will create every new index whenever it deems necessary, add the `myindex` alias and apply the proper mapping to it.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_template/myindex_template -d '{
  "template": "myindex_*",
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "aliases": {
     "myindex": {}
  },
  "mappings": {
    "type": {
      "properties": {
        "Title": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "Raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Then whenever you launch your re-indexing process a new index with a new name will be created BUT with the proper mapping and the proper alias.